# Importing Jar in Play Framework gives me java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, jar, playframework-2.0

I have created a library in java and I am trying to use it in my Java Play Framework application with Intellij.

The documentations tells me that I only need to add it to my lib folder in the project.

Yet, when I type activator run on the terminal, I have the following error(the library is seen in the Intellij and I can use it in my new code):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
at play.api.libs.logback.LogbackLoggerConfigurator.configure(LogbackLoggerConfigurator.scala:80)
at play.api.libs.logback.LogbackLoggerConfigurator.init(LogbackLoggerConfigurator.scala:26)
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:94)
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:65)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:64)
at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala:54)
at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:234)
at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:74)
at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:74)
at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:100)
at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:53)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 13/out/2016 23:37:26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jar is an unmanaged jar, that means it is not part of any sbt repo, then you need to add the following line in your `build.sbt`.

`unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/your_jar.jar")`